# Python: Evaluation of all/any vs spelling them out

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, logic

Let's consider two ways to check for all conditions to be true

Option 1

```
if all([cond1, cond2, cond3]):
  return true
```

Option 2

```
if (cond1 and cond2 and cond3):
  return true
```

Do both evaluate the same way? AFAIR that `all` will fail as soon as one statement fails, making it possible, that a condition can presume that all previously listed conditions evaluated to `true`. E.g. making it safe in Option 1 to access a variable in `cond3`, that was previously (in `cond1` or `cond2`) tested to be accessible. Does that hold true also for Option 2? Also, are there performance differences?

Comment: The and operator short-circuits too, so if `cond1` fails, it won't bother evaluation `cond2`, and `cond3`.

Comment: Thanks! What about performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 has extra performance overhead, needing to create a list, and then iterate over the list. There's also a problem where each condition put into the iterable used in `all()` would have to be computed before checking truthness.

A fine example by @StefanPochmann proves the problems which arise:

```
a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

if a and a[0] > 5:
    pass

if all((a, a[0] > 5)):
    pass

a = []

if a and a[0] > 5:
    pass

if all((a, a[0] > 5)):
    pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/execpad-b1260aab7279/source-b1260aab7279", line 14, in <module>
    if all((a, a[0] > 5)):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can see the snippet run [here](https://eval.in/943048)

Using option 2 is the better choice, unless you are actually validating a list of booleans. Using the `and` operator prevents the checking of contitions past the first one failing, as demonstrated above.

Apart from performance reasons, the code is much easier to read if you use the `and` operator between your conditions. With proper syntax hilighting in an editor, it will become very clear what is going on.